# Frame grabber reverse engineering

Tags: hardware

I have bought a USB frame grabber ([**Hauppauge WinTV HVR 1900**](http://www.hauppauge.co.uk/site/products/data_hvr1900.html)) for a personal research project. A SDK exists, but unfortunately the company does not seem too keen on distributing it. I have to extract frames from a video stream in my software, and although it works perfectly with my webcam stream, it does not work with the frame grabber (that works perfectly with the bundled soft).

**The frame grabber has an integrated MPEG-2 encoder, so the output stream should be MPEG-2**, but since it does not work, I guess it is not standard. VLC is able to read the stream, though. **Since it seems I will have to reverse engineer to get my soft to read the output stream, and as I have never done that kind of thing, could someone please give me a hint on how to proceed about that?** I mostly have experience with the python language.

Answer (score 3):

[VLC is open source](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-sources.html), so if it can indeed read the stream, no reverse engineering required.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So basically, that means I should use VLC as a basis for my own soft? Excuse my lack of experience, but I am a beginner in that field...

Comment: My understanding of your post is that you're trying to figure out the format of the stream and you saw that VLC handles the format. You can debug the data-flow through VLC to see how VLC handles the format, allowing you to understand the format itself.